# Grayscale image background

Tags: android, image, gridview, image-processing

Hello is there a way to grayscale image background? I achieved grayscaling image itself, but not the background :/.

My GridView getView:

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(65, 65));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(13, 13, 13, 13);


        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;

        }
        ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
        matrix.setSaturation(0);

        ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);

        imageView.setImageResource(MainActivity.mThumbIds.get(position));
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);
        imageView.setColorFilter(filter);

        return imageView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you can render the resource to a bitmap, apply the filter to the bitmap, and set the background to the filtered bitmap using a `BitmapDrawable` and `imageView.setBackground(Drawable)`.